# iteration through lookups table in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a lookups table that contains course categories and subcategories separate:

```
{
        "id": 138,
        "lookup": "CRS_CTGRY",
        "attr1": "Arts and Humanities",
        "attr2": "الفنون والعلوم الإنسانية",
        "attr3": null,
        "attr4": null,
        "attr5": null,
        "editable": 1
    },

{
        "id": 155,
        "lookup": "CRS_SB_CTGRY",
        "attr1": "Photography",
        "attr2": "النصوير",
        "attr3": "138",
        "attr4": null,
        "attr5": null,
        "editable": 1
    },
```

The relation between them is that `attr3 = id_of_the_category && attr1 = CRS_SB_CTGRY`

I want to merge them together in one list like:

```
{"id":138,"
"lookup":"CRS_CTRGY",
"name":"Arts and Humanities",
"subcategories":{"id": 154,
                 "lookup": "CRS_SB_CTGRY",
                  "attr1": "Music",
                  "attr2": "الموسيقي",
                  "attr3": "138",
                  "attr4": null,
                   "attr5": null,
                    "editable": 1
}}
```

This is my models.py:

```
class Lookups(models.Model):
lookup = models.CharField(max_length=45)
attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
attr3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
attr4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
attr5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
editable = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'lookups'
    unique_together = (('lookup', 'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', 'attr4', 'attr5'),)
```

How can i do it? and where to put the code? in the serializers class?

Comment: Use code template instead of images to show your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return a nested list of one model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348467/return-a-nested-list-of-one-model)

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what you are trying to do, because your example (text) doesn't match the example (code screenshots).

From your code screenshot it seems that if `lookup` is `CRS_CTGRY`, this is the main category, and if `lookup` is `CRS_SUB_CTGRY`, then this is a sub category, and the parent category id is stored in `attr3`.

Now you want you get a dictionary object for this structure. Assuming you have all the data in your model:

```
combined = []
lookup_indices = {} # stores parents lookup for easier access.

for obj in Lookups.objects.filter(lookup='CRS_CTGY').values():
   obj['subcategories'] = []
   combined.append(obj)
   lookup_indicies[obj.pk] = len(combined) - 1

for obj in Lookups.objects.filter(lookup='CRS_SUB_CTGRY').values():
   try:
      combined[lookup_indicies[int(obj['attr3'])]]['subcategories'].append(obj)
   except KeyError:
      print('No parent id {} found for sub cat {}'.format(obj['attr3'], obj))

print(combined)
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm sorry I used wrong screen shots, and I didn't notice. but your assumption was right. my question is  where I put this code.. in the model serializes?